# How is ElGamal not secure under chosen ciphertext attack, but semantically secure in some cases?

Tags: diffie-hellman, elgamal-encryption, discrete-logarithm

I know that you can create a ciphertext c' using c and then find the corresponding m' for c' which you can use to find m for c. So, doesn't this mean that it is not semantically secure? But I also read that it *is* semantically secure when it meets the DDH assumption. Is there some terminology I'm misunderstanding because that seems contradictory to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the corresponding $m'$ using $c'$ is a chosen cipher text attack. It's possible for a scheme to be semantically secure under certain types of attacks (perhaps something weaker like chosen-plaintext attack), but be broken under heavier attacks (like the chosen ciphertext attack you talk about).

Comment: Oh- that helps clear up a lot of things I misinterpreted. Thanks!